# Bind to Parent Object Property with RelativeSource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, relativesource

I've built a WPF based Treeview with

Item
-Subitem

If Subitem is selected, I would like to display also Properties of Item.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={???} Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I guess I need to use a RelativeSource statement, but not quite sure how to do so.

Comment: what is the type of the control which is supposed to be the source for the binding?

Comment: It's a Treeview, so I guess it would be TreeViewItem.

Comment: Can you provide the XAML for your actual TreeView and its contents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JesseJames has given you the correct way to use RelativeSource but the best you will be able to do with RelativeSource is bind to the TreeViewItem itself, which is just the container for your data object i.e ViewModel, meaning you won't be able to access your data objects properties(easily).

I think in this case binding to the container object would break the View-ViewModel approach you are using. Your best bet would be to create a Parent object within your ViewModel and bind to that object. So that now each object in your collection has a reference to it's parent which can now be bound to directly.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Parent.Name}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Also note that the SelectedItem property returns your data object and not the container.

Comment: This works! Thanks. (I added a property Parent to SubItem and called the constructor with SubItemCollection.Add(new Subitem(name, this);.

Answer (score 8):

```
 {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}, Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Comment: What is typeOfAncestor supposed to be?

Comment: It's the type of the control you want to bind to. Relative Source walks up the visual tree until it finds the first control of x:Type typeOfAncestor.

Comment: I need to bind to the relative object and Item, ItemViewModel etc does not work.

Comment: Type `AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}`

Comment: Could it be possible that there is a conflict to the StackPanel Path=isSelected?

Comment: No, StackPanel "IsSelected" property does not affect your Binding

Comment: @Stef look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255365/wpf-binding-parent-property-in-hierarchicaldatatemplate

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code, try binding simply to `Name`. It appears that your data context should already be set to the `TreeViewItem` due to the following line: `<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}">`. The `RelativeResource` binding is probably looking further up the logical tree and that's why your binding is failing.

Comment: Just binding to name returns the selected item.

Comment: Ah I think I had misunderstood your question. I'll think about this a bit more and get back to you.